# Adding XML node on the basis of TextBox entry inside WPF Form

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose i have created a WPF form having one text box. i am calling that form inside another wpf window's gridpanel and after entering value inside the textbox, i am clicking on submit button. After button click, i need to get that value and save it in string form inside my current class. My logic is something like this.

For getting the from inside my current window:-

```
void SelectedClick(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    selectedItem.ContextMenu = VcontextMenu;
    VcontextMenu.Items.Add(VmenuItem1);
    VmenuItem1.Click += AddValidation;
    details();
}

void AddValidation(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ValidationForm obj = new ValidationForm();
    ProcessGrid.Content = obj.VForm;
}
```

Now i want to store the value of my textbox inside a string. For that i have used following code:-

```
    public void details()
    {
        ValidationForm obj = new ValidationForm();
        string str = obj.s.ToString();
    }
```

My ValidationForm Code:-

```
public partial class ValidationForm : UserControl
    {
        public string s { get; set; }
        public ValidationForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void XSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            s = TextValidationName.Text;
        }
    }
```

but instead of opening the form, the control is going to obj.s.ToString() and showing error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Check your obj, it's null.
You cannot reach obj without giving value.

Comment: From where are you calling the `details()` function? Post `ValidationForm` code also.

Comment: I have added my ValidationForm code and i am calling details function from selectedClick method

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused since the string `s` in your `ValidationForm` class is not assigned. It is probably caused since the `XSave_Click()` method is not being called.

Ensure that you properly assign the value to `s` before you try to get value from it.

Comment: yeah that's true. when i am calling selectedClick method by right clicking on context menu then it should load the form but it is not loading the form and just passing the control to details function.i am not able to find error that why it's not loading the form in the processgrid.

Comment: Are you trying to display the ValidateForm user control to user and expecting an input?

Comment: `Window window = new Window 
    {
        Title = "ValidationForm",
        Content = new ValidationForm()
    };

    window.ShowDialog();`